# Presses on the accelerator

Tags: phrases

> Michael is in a car and is backing away from some cops, trying to flee
> from them. Michael then sees that there is another cop behind him, so
> he turns the speed up a little (he's still backing) to hit him.

How could I describe in a natural way that he turns the speed up a little of an already moving car?

Could I say "presses on the accelerator"? Would that be natural?

Michael presses on the accelerator, plowing into the cop behind him.

Or maybe "steps on the gas"? Or would that sound like his foot wasn't on the accelerator already?

Michael steps on the gas, plowing into the cop behind him.

Comment: turns the speed up a little is not right. **presses the accelerator** OR steps on the gas. I guess he forgot he had the car in reverse....

Comment: _Puts his foot down_ is also used to mean _presses harder on the accelerator to increase his speed_.

Comment: Another phrase that would fit is "floored it"

Comment: First of all, how can he hit the car behind him if he is accelerating? Accelerating would be moving forward. I think you mean decelerating. But then again he might get busted if he decelerates. Is he moving in the reverse direction?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use "accelerate". In my mind it's clear that he is driving backward, and "accelerate" would mean to speed up in the current direction.

> ...there is another cop behind him, so he **accelerates** to hit him.

If in doubt, you could also add some phrasing to clarify that he is hitting the police car with the back of his car:

> ...there is another cop behind him, so he accelerates to hit him **with his rear bumper**

That said, "speeds up", "steps on the gas", "hits the gas", "floors it", and "presses the accelerator" all get the point across with varying degrees of intensity and style ("speeds up" is probably the least "intense" while "floors it" implies maximum acceleration).

Comment: Since I don't have the reputation to comment to the OP: @dhanishtha-ghosh "Accelerate" means to speed up, period. It does not matter the direction. You can accelerate while driving in reverse, increasing your backward speed. "Decelerating", in contrast, means to slow down. Whether you are driving forward or in reverse, decelerating means slowing down.